# Having to click Twice to get one response

Tags: javascript

I have made a dropdown that appears on click on a button. Pretty simple, except for how I have to click twice to get the js function to execute. After I click it the first, it appears and disappears like it should - taking only one click. I have no clue why it would require this and have searched for fixes, but none of them seem to work.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="resources-menu">
    <li>
        <button onclick="res()" id="resbut" onblur="setTimeout('reshide()', 175)">Resources</button>
        <ul id="resblock">
            <li style="padding-bottom: 20px; text-align:center;padding-top:25px">
                <button onclick="dirlnk()">Directory</button>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.resources-menu {
    width:88px;
    float:left;
}
#resbut {
    font-weight:700;
    height:30px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-color: black;
}
ul.resources-menu, ul.resources-menu ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: relative;
}
#resblock {
    width: 90px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    border:solid;
    border-color:black;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function res() {
    if (document.getElementById('resblock').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('resblock').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.background = "lightblue";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomRightRadius = "0px";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "0px";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottom = "none";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.textDecoration = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('resblock').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.background = "";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomRightRadius = "";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottom = "";
        document.getElementById('resbut').style.textDecoration = "";
    }
}
function reshide() {
    document.getElementById('resblock').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('resbut').style.background = "";
    document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomRightRadius = "";
    document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottomLeftRadius = "";
    document.getElementById('resbut').style.borderBottom = "";
    document.getElementById('resbut').style.textDecoration = "";
}
function dirlnk() {
    window.location = "/Portal/directory";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the `style` property when it's in the CSS files, not a `style` attribute. Use `getComputedStyle` instead:

```
function res() {
    var resblock = document.getElementById('resblock');
    var resblockStyle = resblock.style;
    var resbutStyle = document.getElementById('resbut').style;
    if (getComputedStyle(resblock).display === 'none') {
        resblockStyle.display = 'block';
        resblockStyle.background = "lightblue";
        resbutStyle.borderBottomRightRadius = "0px";
        resbutStyle.borderBottomLeftRadius = "0px";
        resbutStyle.borderBottom = "none";
        resbutStyle.textDecoration = "none";
    } else {
        reshide();
    }
}
function reshide() {
    var resblockStyle = document.getElementById('resblock').style;
    var resbutStyle = document.getElementById('resbut').style;
    resblockStyle.display = 'none';
    resbutStyle.background = "";
    resbutStyle.borderBottomRightRadius = "";
    resbutStyle.borderBottomLeftRadius = "";
    resbutStyle.borderBottom = "";
    resbutStyle.textDecoration = "";
}
function dirlnk() {
    window.location.href = "/Portal/directory";
}
```

It's also a good idea to cache your variables so you don't need to query the DOM for each style addition. Your `reshide` function does the same thing as the else in your `res` function -- you should avoid duplicating code where practicable.

#### Compatibility issues

As @garromark correctly notes, this solution won't work if you need to support older browsers (i.e. IE8 and below). Alternatively, you can add a class called `.no-display` and check whether that class is present or not:

```
.no-display {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then your JavaScript check:

```
if (/\bno\-display\b/.test(resblock.className)) {
```

Comment: Ahhhhh so what was happening was it would go to the else statement and set it to none and the the second click would set it to block! Thank you very much! (it works)

Comment: @HarrisonGibbs: yes, because it didn't know that the style was meant to be hidden, it "hides" it again, and since it then knows it's hidden it shows it on the second click.

Comment: Note: `getComputedStyle()` is not backwards compatible with with IE8 and previous versions of IE.  Consider using a library like jQuery (1.x) and `$.is(':visible')` if you care about backward compatibility with IE.

Comment: @garromark: true, if you have to you can also use a class called `.no-display` or something like that and check for the presence of that.